# Detect content in textarea (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, textarea, detect

How do I check if there's any content in `<textarea>` ? I need to addClass based on that condition.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if($.trim($('textarea').val()).length){
     $(this).addClass('someclass');
}
```

Comment: jAndy - +1 but it may not be a bad idea to use `$.trim()` in case the markup has any whitespace.